# Matlab hardlim (step) function does not have exact step

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, data-visualization, matlab, function

[`Hardlim` matlab function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/hardlim.html?s_tid=doc_ta) should look like a step:

[image]

But the code provided at the documentation page

```
n = -5:0.1:5;
a = hardlim(n);
plot(n,a)
```

gives me this output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The error you see is caused by the plotting: You sample the function from $-5$ to $5$ with step size $0.1$, and plot these values.

```
...    
-0.2 => 0
-0.1 => 0
 0   => 1
 0.1 => 1
...
```

Plotting module then connects these points with a line that looks exactly like your image.

Comment: I understood but ıf you show this graph a pupil he will say different. Already math formula and math graphs isnt common? I think this is matlab's error. Thanks for editing and answer.

Comment: Isnt it a bug @jan kukacka

Comment: It is not a bug. This is how `plot` works: You give it (x,y) coordinates and it draws a line going through them. If you want to plot the step function exactly (i.e. draw the step line), you need to give it corresponding coordinates: `plot([-1,0,0,1], [0,0,1,1])`

Comment: I got but finally the graphs express as an example -0.2=0.2 .Then it is bug in my opinion @jan